# Updating styles outside of a components scope - Angular 2

Tags: css, angular, angular2-directives

I am creating a very simple web app using Angular 2 that asks the user to input an RGB color code. After the user inputs the code, the page background should change to the inputted color.

Currently, this is what I have in my `app.component.ts` file:

```
 /**
   * Fired when the user clicks the #update-background button. This function will read the current input values and set the background color to these values.
   * 
   * @param rgb: RGB object bound to the input fields. Holds the rgb(,,) values for the new background  
   */
  updateBackgroundColor(rgb) {
    // 1. Construct the new background color
    var updatedBackgroundColor = "rgb(" + rgb.r + "," + rgb.g + "," + rgb.b + ")";

    // 2. Set the background of the <body> to the new background color. Right now I am using direct DOM manipulation because I could not find a way to access the <body> via typescript. 
    document.body.style.background = updatedBackgroundColor;
  }
```

Is this best way to update the `<body>` element's style? The code is currently working ([demo](https://bjoberg.github.io/kolours///)), but I just want to be sure this is the most efficient way to access the `<body>` element via typescript and Angular 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is right, we can't dynamically change style of an element using class selector.

Comment: if you need further clarification, use chrome dev tool and inspect website like apple.com. These sites have animation updating in style attribute of element.